# Show toast soon as activity is visible

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-lifecycle, android-toast

I'm trying to show a toast whenever the activity is visible to user but the message is not displaying at all.

I've the activity X which at certain point calls:

```
    Intent t = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    t.putExtra( "toast", getString(R.string.subscribingInBackground));
    t.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(t);
    finish();
```

And at MainActivity besides lots of other stuff I've:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (this.adView != null) {
            this.adView.resume();
        }


            String toast = getIntent().getStringExtra("toast");
            if (toast != null)
                Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

but `toast` is always null

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I've checked toast is null by debugging

Comment: You're not calling the `show()` function (`Toast.makeText(...).show()`). That won't make `toast` not null, but still.

Comment: I've noticed I forgot to `.show()` after makeText, but not working yet since `toast` is always null

Comment: Please  try to use get string from xml as  `getResources().getString(R.string.subscribingInBackground);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `FLAG_REORDER_TO_FRONT` suggests that you believe that the activity already exists. If so, that activity will be called with `onNewIntent()`, and the `Intent` delivered to `onNewIntent()` will have your extra. `getIntent()` returns the `Intent` that was used to create the activity initially.

Comment: Your assumption is true, the activity already exists. But you didn't explain how can i get the `newIntent`

Comment: @RafaelLima: You override `onNewIntent()`. The `Intent` is supplied as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code

package com.example.abc.introscreen;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent t = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        t.putExtra( "toast", "Hello");
        startActivity(t);

        }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        String toast = getIntent().getStringExtra("toast");

        if (toast != null)
            Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onResume();

    }


}




    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onNewIntent()` to get the `Intent` which you used in `ActivityX` to start `MainActivity`.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) on `Activity`

> Note that `getIntent()` still returns the original Intent. You can use `setIntent(Intent)` to update it to this new Intent.

So you can override `onNewIntent()` as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Then your `Toast` will be displayed.